# Filling up a window screen dynamically (horizontally and vertically)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create a grid for my website that would fill up the entire document (with no overflow/scroll). How would I make it so that elements could be added if the screen is resized? I have tried using a grid (which helps with the vertical filling), but I haven't figured out how to fill it horizontally. So that the DOM is always full with elements?

Here are Images of what I mean
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqGto.png)

[Image with window size increased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqSQe.png)

What I have so far:

```
<div class="photo-grid" style="display: grid;">
  <div class="card card-tall card-wide">1</div>
  <div class="card card-tall">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card card-wide">7</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
  <div class="card">10</div>
  <div class="card">11</div>
  <div class="card">12</div>
</div>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap');

.photo-grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 240px;
}

/* Medium screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-tall {
    grid-row: span 2 / auto;
  }

  .card-wide {
    grid-column: span 2 / auto;
  }
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #353535;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(3, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.15rem 0.5rem, rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.075rem 0.175rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 500ms;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

How would I go about trying to solve this problem?

Comment: As to how (re)fill the screen when the browser's size changes, you simply provide enough content (by default, in any situation) to deal with the largest supported resolution/situation. On smaller screens (phones, tablets, low res pc, ...) you simply apply `display: none` to the excess items.

Comment: But as for how to implement the html/css, that very much depends on all the little details of the desired style. How do you want it to look on fullscreen 4k, on 1080, on .... you have to figure out what your (resolution) cut-off points will be, and then mock up how it should look between all those points. (the popular bootstrap stylesheet for example has 4 or 5 cutoff points, which allows one to define **xs/sm/md/lg/xl**-versions; i suspect that mocking up your "biggest supported version" and deciding how many versions you'll want in total are the first steps you should take.

Comment: What do you know about the dimensions of the items? Are they constrained to be 1, 2 or 4 square units? And must they always make rows? Or might they be more randomly sized? And what if there weren’t 2 convenient items to fill that third column first row? What you have shown is very regular, but we need to know what the rules for sizing items are.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, they must always fill up the rows.  Some may be more randomly sized. What do you mean about the convenient items to fill the third row? Yes the columns should always be filled with items -- though the CSS should fill up the upper most rows, it should be a problem filling up the final row that should be displayed.

Comment: @Raxi Would you kindly be able to give me a link to the bootstrap stylesheet that you mentioned?  Are these the cut off points that you mentioned? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/  Thank you very much for your idea.

Comment: By convenient I meant that it just so happened that the 3rd and 4th items exactly filled up the space at the end of the first row. What if there had been one rectangular one in portrait mode and one in landscape. Are you wanting the items to resize to fit?